# How to create dummy variables from a factor?

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to create a set of dummy variables from a factor.

For example, the `mtcars` dataset has `cyl` values `4`, `6`, and `8`. I would like to create a set of variables such as:
`four_six` with `4` coded as `0` and `6` coded as `1`. I eventually want to create other variables like:
`six_eight`, `four_eight`.

I tried something like this using `ifelse`

```
four_six <- ifelse(cyl == 4, 0, 1)
```

But I would like to recode the sixes as `1`, instead of everything as `1`.
[image]

For example, I would like the eights coded as missing/NA.

Also, is there a way to programmatically do this with other functions?

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another condition

```
four_six <- ifelse(cyl == 4, 0, ifelse(cyl==6, 1, NA))
```

or use `dplyr::case_when`

```
four_six <- dplyr::case_when(cyl==4 ~ 0, cyl==6 ~ 1)
```